# FB.Data.query with better performance

Tags: javascript, events, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using this code for take user's events from facebook:

```
var query = FB.Data.query("select eid,name,start_time,location,venue,pic_small,pic_big,description from event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid={0}) AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time LIMIT 10", 
            uid);                       
query.wait(function(rows) {
   ...
}
```

but it's very slow. is there any way for get better performance?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing it to [`FB.api()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) instead:

```
var fql = "select eid, name, start_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=0) AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time LIMIT 10";
FB.api("/fql?=" + fql, function(response) {
  ...
});
```